# multiply value from database to my textbox

Tags: php, mysql

i have 1 table named sales and the ff fields in it are

```
id | total_fields |

1  |  100         |
```

now myproblem is that  how to multiply the values in textbox into the value of table which is "total_fields".what i want is that when i input value  from my textbox in line 60 and click updatesale.php on line 66 the total value of my "total_fields" must be multiplied to what value i input into my textbox. so if i input 2 "total_fields" must be 200and if i input 3 "total_fields" must be 300. i tried anything what i've learn but i can't get exactly what i am looking for. any idea is very helpful for me.

```
    <?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("inventory", $con);
 $f=$_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sales where code = '".$f."' GROUP BY pcode");



function formatMoney($number, $fractional=false) {
    if ($fractional) {
        $number = sprintf('%.2f', $number);
    }
    while (true) {
        $replaced = preg_replace('/(-?\d+)(\d\d\d)/', '$1,$2', $number);
        if ($replaced != $number) {
            $number = $replaced;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    return $number;
}   

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
      {
    $pcode = $row['pcode'];
     $totalretail = 0;
     $qty_tot = 0;
     $rr_tot = 0;
     $vats_tot = 0;
     $final_tot = 0;
     $item_amount = 0;
     $result_info = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sales where pcode = '".$pcode."'");
        while($row_info = mysql_fetch_array($result_info)){

            $name = $row_info['name'];
            $qty = $row_info['qty'];
            $ppp=$row_info['PRICE'];
            $rr=$row_info['total'];
            $id = $row_info["id"];
            $vats = $row_info["vats"]; 
            $percent = $row_info["percent"];
            $qty_tot += $qty; 
            $rr_tot += $ppp; 
            $item_amount += $ppp;
            $totalretail += $rr;
            $vats_tot += $vats; 

            }
           echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td style = "background-image:url(images/buts1.png);border:0px;"><div align="center" style = "color:black">'.$pcode.'</div></td>';
            echo '<td style = "background-image:url(images/buts1.png);border:0px;><div align="center" >&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$name.'</div></td>';
           echo '<td style = "background-image:url(images/buts1.png);border:0px;><div align="center">'.$qty_tot.'</div></td>';
            echo '</div></td>';
            echo '<td>'.$vats_tot.'</td>';
            echo '<input type = "text" name = "multiply"  style = "width:30px;"/>';     
            echo '</div></td>';
            echo '<td style = "border:0px;background-image:url(images/buts1.png)">';
            echo formatMoney ($totalretail , true);
            echo '</div></td>';
           echo '<td style = "background-image:url(images/buts1.png);border:0px;">';
            echo '<a  href=updatesales.php?id=' . $row["id"] .'>update |</a>';
            echo '<a  href=delete.php?id=' . $row["id"] .'>Cancel</a>';
            echo '</td>';

          echo '</tr>';

     }      
     mysql_close($con);
     ?>
```

Comment: simply add form tags for each row and post the value of textbox and apply your logic there.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely clear what problem you're having, but I'm assuming you want to do the calculation on the server (rather than in the browser), and perhaps save the multiplied value back to the database, and you're having issues getting the user-inputted value to your PHP code? Sorry if I've misunderstood - you might want to clarify your question a little if I have.

It looks like your code emits a single row of an HTML table containing some links to other PHP scripts, but it doesn't contain a form. You should place your input inside a form, set it's action attribute to the appropriate script (e.g. `action='updatesales.php?id='.$row['id']`) & its `method="post"`, and replace the link you emit on line 66 with a submit button (`<input type="submit" value="update" />`, also inside the `<form>`).

This will mean when you click the submit button, an HTTP POST will be sent to your updatesales script. You can then access the value of the textbox (if you're using a web framework, it may have its own preferred way of doing this; if not, you can use `$_POST['multiply']`). That value will be a string, so you'll probably want to convert it with `intval()` or `floatval()`.

At that point, you can perform the multiplication and do whatever you need to with the resulting value - I'm not entirely clear what that is from your question.

(As an aside, the HTML being echo'ed out looks invalid - I think there are a few `</div></td>` that don't need to be there)